# Does discount rate and cost of capital mean the same thing to compute levelised cost of energy (LCOE)?

Tags: time-series, investment, capital, discount-rate, discount

I came to understand that `cost of capital` and `discount rate` are two different parameters, although they are also used interchangeably. Discount rate is used to get the future value of a technology in terms of present value. While cost of capital is the rate of return expected to make a risky investment viable.

This is a simplified formula of Levelised Cost of Electricity (LCOE):
[image]

`r` is mentioned as discount rate. So, does discount rate and cost of capital mean the same thing in terms of LCOE?